# how to pass a string with cucumber expressions?

Tags: java, cucumber

I'm a new in automated test with cucumber .i have a maven project and i try to pass a string but i have this *error* .

```
Feature: writing a sentence

Scenario: As a admin i want to write a sentence

Given write a subject "Administrator" 
When write a verb
Then write a complement
```

```
@Given("write a subject {string}")
public void writeSubject(String text)
{
    System.out.println(text);
    System.out.println("lamia");
}
```

> cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 15
>   write a subject {string}
>                  ^
>       at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend.addStepDefinition(JavaBackend.java:156)
>       at cucumber.runtime.java.MethodScanner.scan(MethodScanner.java:68)
>       at cucumber.runtime.java.MethodScanner.scan(MethodScanner.java:41)
>       at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend.loadGlue(JavaBackend.java:86)
>       at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.(Runtime.java:92)
>       at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.(Runtime.java:70)
>       at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.(Runtime.java:66)
>       at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.createRuntime(Cucumber.java:80)
>       at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.(Cucumber.java:59)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
>       at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
>       at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
>       at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:90)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:76)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:49)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:525)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
>   Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 15
>   write a subject {string}
>                  ^
>       at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.regex.Pattern.closure(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.regex.Pattern.(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
>       at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend.pattern(JavaBackend.java:203)
>       at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend.addStepDefinition(JavaBackend.java:151)
>       ... 25 more

Comment: Which version of cucumber are you using?

Comment: Looks like your version of Cucumber doesn't support Cucumber expressions yet.

Comment: thnx i resolved my problem

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
@Given("write a subject (.*)")
public void writeSubject(final String text){
   System.out.println(text);
   System.out.println("lamia");
 }
```

Comment: i try this and  work but i like to use the cucumber expressions not the expressions regex

Comment: I think this is the best way to do that.

Comment: accept the answer if its work fine and upvote which help others.

Comment: just use empty { } bracket intead of { string }

Comment: doesn't work for me . the cucumber expressions {int} {string} .... don't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the specific feature file's step:

```
Scenario: As an admin, I want to write a sentence
      Given write a subject <Administrateur>
```

And in the Java step:

```
  @Given("^write a subject \"([^\"]*)\"")
  public void writeSubject(final String text){...
```

Comment: thanks for this solution but i like to use the cucumber expression

Comment: not sure but try this @Given("write a subject {text}")

Comment: doesn't work for me . the cucumber expressions {int} {string} .... don't work for me